# Error Utilizing Static Map in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, static

Dropping into my error handler on the `GetCallOrPut = map(legOption)` line.  The value getting passed in is = "C".  The map is initializing right when I step through it and i can't seem to figure out what i'm missing.  I have two other functions that utilize a similar map and having no trouble there. Any thoughts?

```
Public Function GetCallOrPut(ByVal legOption As String) As String
    'Translates C to Call and P to Put in option Structure

    Static map As Collection

    If map Is Nothing Then
        Set map = New Collection
        map.Add "C", "Call"
        map.Add "P", "Put"
    End If

    GetCallOrPut = map(legOption)

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Key in a collection is the second argument.

Also use Dim instead of Static:

```
Public Function GetCallOrPut(ByVal legOption As String) As String
    'Translates C to Call and P to Put in option Structure

    Static map As Collection

    If map Is Nothing Then
        Set map = New Collection
        map.Add "Call", "C"
        map.Add "Put", "P"
    End If


    GetCallOrPut = map(legOption)

End Function
```

Comment: thanks!  Had them reversed.  I'm using static for efficiency reasons and it seems to be working fine;  Should I not be able to use static?  This function runs many times over and over again from a worksheet change event from live data feeding into the sheet.

Comment: If it works for you then okay but as I understand it does not matter as it is in the Sub and as soon as the sub finishes the collection is released and needs to be reinstated each time.  So static is not necessary.

Comment: @ScottCraner - if the variable is declared as being `Static`, it isn't released at the end of the function.  At least it **shouldn't** be (that's the whole point of the `Static` keyword), and it wasn't in the limited testing I did.

Comment: @YowE3K fascinating.  But it can not be called by a different function or sub, correct?

Comment: Yes, it can be called from other functions or subs.  I'm not sure what will trigger memory cleanup on it, but it certainly persists for quite some time.

Comment: Oops - sorry - misunderstood what you meant.  No, the variable is only local in scope, so can't be accessed by anything outside the function in which it is defined.

Comment: I did some testing as well stepping through and @YowE3K is correct on the static keyword.

Comment: I've also used the same name map in multiple functions so they are private to each function they're in.

Comment: @StormsEdge If the collection is the same then why not make it a public variable and fill it when the workbook opens?  Then your function is only the one line.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sorry I didn't explain that properly.  I use the same collection name across the different functions.  They all contain different keys and such